# Is it ok to use subclasses to define just a couple of attributes?

Tags: python, inheritance, configuration

I'm working with some code left from other developers. Here we have several projects we can work with. The project object is instantiated at the runtime. Then it used in other classes. There are no methods in Projects and the class holds pure configuration values.

Is subclassing a proper way to define configuration for different Projects? Isn't it better to create one class and get values from configuration file?

```
class BaseProject(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    """
    abstract class for projects
    concrete version of this needed only to keep transition IDs in case of custom workflow.
    """
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def project_id(self):
        pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def transition_id(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def by_name(name):
        for prj in BaseProject.__subclasses__():
            if name.lower() == prj.__name__.lower():
                return prj()
        return Project3()

    @staticmethod
    def by_card_name(name):
        for prj in BaseProject.__subclasses__():
            if name.split("-")[0].lower() == str(prj.__name__).lower():
                return prj()
        return Project3()


# concrete projects
class Project1(BaseProject):
    project_id = 12334
    transition_id = 444


class Project2(BaseProject):
    project_id = 4451
    transition_id = 88


class Project3(BaseProject):
    project_id = 12346
    transition_id = 88
```

It looks good in term of open/closed principle. But I'm a little confused that values are in classes themself not in configuration.

BTW we don't expect any more projects in future and existing are hardly to change.

Comment: Pseudo-code is off-topic. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: This might be more on-topic over at [SoftwareEngineering](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/), but before posting there please [**follow their tour**](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very famous quote in software engineering: The only fixed thing in software is change.

So if it doesn't seem to you face any change in the future, that not means that you won't face any change in the future.

But there is something in your code. The instances of your class have no property for themselves. All values are `static`. This doesn't seem good. If you have a real object in your code that represents a project, so that object should has its own values.

So I think you should remove that `static` notations from your code and make those properties owned by instance. If it's applicable for you, then inheritance for creating different kinds of `Project`s are a really good thing to do.

But If you think you should not remove those `static` values, inheriting is still a good idea. Because you can pass different types of Projects in your code without modifying it.

Comment: Thank you. I think you right I also would like to move the attributes to the object itself. But my idea was to store values in configuration. Something like
`class Project:
    def __init__(self, project_name):
        self.project_id, self._transition_id = Config.get_project_config(project_name)`

Comment: That is another way for doing this, But I think, in that case, it's also better that `get_project_cofig` returns an instance of `Project`. But if you want to do this, I think `Project` class is redundant.

Comment: Yes, in configuration I store them as named tuples and `get_project_config` just looks up a right one. By the some reason I think it's more readable.  Thank you for helping me